# Stirling's Formula approach to probability problem

Tags: probability

I am having trouble with this question: A game warden, who does not have the reputation of a genius of probability theory, wishes to estimate the number of wolves in a certain forest. He does this by trapping 1,000 wolves and placing a band around the leg of each trapped wolf. He then releases these wolves and proceeds later to gather a random sample of 1,000 wolves (without replacement) of which 100 have bands. The game warden concludes that there must be 1,900 wolves in the forest. Do you think that this estimate supports his reputation as a non-genius?

Our professor hinted that we should Stirling's Formula in order to answer this question. However, I have no idea where to even begin. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If there really are $1900$ wolves in the forest (which is technically possible) and $1000$ of them are marked, then when he went out to capture the wolves the second time, he *just so happened to capture ALL 900 of the unmarked wolves*.  That seems **incredibly** unlikely to occur (how unlikely can be well approximated using stirling's formula).  A more logical conclusion from the catch and release procedure is that $10\%$ of those captured the second time are marked, so the marked should describe approximately $10\%$ of the total population, i.e. approx $10000$ wolves in the forest.

Comment: Thank you! How would you estimate the probability using Stirling's Formula? Do you plug 1,900 or 1,000 in for n?

Comment: If there are exactly $1900$ wolves, where exactly $900$ of which are unmarked, $1000$ of which are marked, what is the *exact* probability of having selected all $900$ of the unmarked wolves when selecting $1000$ of them at random?  (This should feel similar to something like a poker probability question if you have practiced those)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ wolves in the forest.
Then, if we suppose that every wolf is equally likely to be captured, we can capture $1000$ wolves in a total of $\binom{n}{1000} = \frac{n!}{1000!(n-1000)!}$ different ways.
However, we capture $100$ wolves with band, which can happen in $\binom{1000}{100} = \frac{1000!}{100!900!}$ different ways, and $900$ without band, which can happen in $\binom{n-1000}{900} = \frac{(n-1000)!}{900!(n-1900)!}$ ways. So the probability of catching $100$ wolves with and $900$ wolves without band is
$$ P_n = \frac{(1000!(n-1000)!)^2}{(n!900!)^2(n-1000)!(n-1900)!}.$$
So the question is, for what $n$ is this most likely?
Is it for $n=1900$, which gives $P_{1900} \approx 5 \times 10^{-430}$? Or $n=10000$, which gives $P_{10000} \approx 0.044$? Which seems to confirm our suspicion that the warden is not too bright.
Note that those values are approximated using Wolfram Alpha, and Stirling's formula can be used to approximate the factorials with exponents.